# Will Ahmadis enter Jannah according to the Quran?

Tags: ahmadiyyah

99.9% of the time, whenever Muslims are confronted with questions like 'Will Islamic God send Hindus, e.g, to Islamic Paradise', their response is, 'Allah will forgive every sin except Shirk', and how every Muslim will be taken out of hellfire eventually, as Allah will forgive every sin except Shirk.

Ahmadis don't commit Shirk so according to the Quran, they will be forgiven as Allah will forgive every sin except Shirk?

Now, I know, ofcourse you will have your own conclusions and you will never accept this but pls answer this question having this Quranic verse and Hadith in mind:

> Surely Allah does not forgive that anything should be associated with
> Him, and forgives what is besides that to whomsoever He pleases; and
> whoever associates anything with Allah, he devises indeed a great sin. [[4:48]](https://quran.com/4/48?translations=18,19,22,85,95,84)
>
> When the people of Paradise will enter Paradise and the people of Hell
> will go to Hell, Allah will order those who have had faith equal to
> the weight of a grain of mustard seed to be taken out from Hell. [[Bukhari 22]](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:22)
> (Believing Allah as your God is for sure more than a mustard of faith)

Pls don't come up with 'All the Muslims are unanimously agreed that Ahmadis are not Muslims' and you can't go against the Ijma! If that is the case, Ibn Taymiyyah (who went against the Ijma in many things e.g the Talaq Issue), or Salafis of today are going to hellfire as they rejected many things on which there was Ijma..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Islamic creed is that anyone who dies while being a Muslim will *eventually* go to heaven while anyone who dies while being a disbeliever will remain in hell.

Regarding the verse that Allah will forgive anything less than Shirk, you misunderstand what shirk means here. Shirk has multiple meanings, one is polytheism while another is kufr - disbelief.

> الشرك والكفر قد يطلقان بمعنى واحد وهو الكفر بالله
>
> Kufr and shirk may carry the same meaning, which is disbelief in Allah
>
> <sup>— [Nawawi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1711/315)</sup>

For example consider the hadith:

> بين الرجل وبين الشرك والكفر ترك الصلاة
>
> Between a man and Shirk and Kufr there stands his giving up the Salat.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:82b)</sup>

Obviously abandoning salah is not shirk in the meaning of polytheism, because one who denies salah does not necessarily start worshiping an idol. Rather shirk is used in the meaning of kufr.

Similarly in 4:48 Shirk means Kufr. This is also evident by the fact that there are verses which say that Allah will never forgive Kufr:

> إن الذين كفروا وظلموا لم يكن الله ليغفر
>
> Indeed, those who disbelieve and commit wrong - **never will Allah forgive them**
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:168](http://quran.com/4/168)</sup>

> إن الذين كفروا وصدوا عن سبيل الله ثم ماتوا وهم كفار فلن يغفر الله لهم
>
> Indeed, those who disbelieved and averted [people] from the path of Allah and then died while they were disbelievers - **never will Allah forgive them**.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 47:34](http://quran.com/47/34)</sup>

> لهم إن تستغفر لهم سبعين مرة فلن يغفر الله لهم ذلك بأنهم كفروا بالله ورسوله
>
> [Even] If you should ask forgiveness for them seventy times - **never will Allah forgive them**. That is because they disbelieved in Allah and His Messenger
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:80](http://quran.com/9/80)</sup>

One who disbelieves in the finality of the prophethood with Muhammad ﷺ commits Kufr, as he denies the verse of the Quran ([33:40](https://quran.com/33/40)) and its agreed upon interpretation. The prophet wished to execute the envoys of Musaylimah ([Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/285)), and this would make no sense if he considered them to be believers. Simialrly the sahaba fought and killed Musaylimah, Al-Aswad al-Ansi and other pretenders and their followers. It would be unlawful for them to shed blood of someone who was a muslim.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post they're on, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points.